# How to check valid contact number? Not format like if it actually exist or not without sending verification message?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, whatsapp

I am developing chrome extension to send messages in BULK via WhatsApp. The problem I am currently facing is that I cannot validate phone number. I have used regex to check format and length. But still its not enough. By term invalid contact number, I meant to say that the number does not exist or belong to a person. I have seen a lot of questions on stack overflow but most of them are about checking contact numbers with regex.
The major problem occurs when an invalid number comes in a list it stops sending msgs to remaining numbers. I cannot control it. So, I want to check invalid numbers and avoid sending request to them. Kindly guide me in this.
I want to use like API or something like that to check if number actually exist. I'm having trouble with this, and I was wondering if anyone could help me out. As I'm feeling stuck and don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Do you want to check phone numbers that are in the correct format but do not have a subscriber? That is impossible.

Comment: If you're sending unsolicited messages to numbers you don't know then it's spam. I don't list my number anywhere to avoid having to deal with people who would invade my privacy this way.

Comment: my question is different than others because I am using regex to check format and length. like I have put a check that a number must start with + and then country code and then there must exist 10 digits with type number. But if a person entered lets suppose +92 000 000 0000. then its valid according to my regex but actually such number does not exist.

Comment: Its for university use like if a professor want to send messages to its students etc. a professor will have a list of contact number students but what if the list contain invalid number? or by mistake someone has entered invalid number?

Comment: there are many WhatsApp bulk message sender at Google playstore. I want to develop something like them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This API does just what you've described:
https://rapidapi.com/inutil-inutil-default/api/bulk-whatsapp-validator/

This one too: https://apify.com/inutil_labs/wscrp-free